# R How to delete selected row in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How to delete selected Rows in R.

I have Data frame (stock) like give below

```
100, A, B
101, B, C 
102, A, B
103, B, C 
104, A, B
105, B, C
```

And I have vector (vec) list like given below.

```
101
104
106
```

Want to delete all rows in data frame that are  present in the vector list.

I tried to achieve the same with subset function but I get error/ warning

```
subset(stock,stock$col1 == vec)

Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(stock$col1, vec) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

How do I delete all rows in data frame that are  present in the vector list. Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the rows of data frame whose cells match a given vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004203/remove-the-rows-of-data-frame-whose-cells-match-a-given-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
stock <- stock[-vec, ]
```

And yes, this is a duplicate and you probably should have spent more time searching the Stack Overflow database.

Comment: sorry, If it is duplicated. But I tired searching in stack over flow and found I should use subset and i tired with subset function accordingly. Since got error with subset  I made this post.  Thanks anyway I helped saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

```
    stock<-stock[!stock$col1 %in% vec[,1],]
```